Set neovim keymap for lazily loaded plugin within plugin's lua file
For my neovim config, I use lazy as a package manage and I separate my plugin configs into their own files in /nvim/lua/plugins.
I recently installed [Glow][1], which I will only need on occasion, so it should be loading lazily (as it does).
On top of this setup, I try to set the key bindings for each plugin within its respective lua file. But now I have the problem, if a plugin loads lazily and I set the keymap within the plugin, the keymap may not be loaded early enough. See for example this Glow setup:
return
{
    'ellisonleao/glow.nvim',
    config = function()
        require("glow").setup({})
        vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-M>, ":Glow<CR>", { desc = "Open Markdown Preview" }
    end,
    cmd = "Glow",
}

Upon my key press, nothing happens. However, if I call ":Glow" within neovim, the plugin is loaded. Once that happened, I can use the shortcut as well. Obviously, I would like to use the shortcut for the first open as well.
So: (How) is it possible, to set a keymap within a plugins respective lua file, where the keymap is set immediately while the plugin is lazily loaded?

In this case, I could call the setup function when setting up the given lsp. So in my lsp-zero.lua file, I added the glow setup to the ltex setup and that did the trick
require('lspconfig').ltex.setup({
    -- set up glow on ltex create such that it can be opened via keymap
    require('glow').setup()
})

The glow.lua file didn't change
